# ローカル環境でwordpressの管理画面に繋がらない

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

MAMPを使ってローカル環境を作り、ワードプレスで作られたサイトを修正しています。
Mysqlのデータベースやサイトの情報をサーバーからダウンロードして、ローカル環境でページを表示する事ができましたが、wp-admin（もしくはwp-login.php）にアクセスするとローカルサーバーに繋がらなくなります。

wp-configファイルや.htaccessの記載などに問題があるのでしょうか？
何かお気づきの点などあれば、助けて頂けると幸いです。

作業環境
mac book pro
macos monterey

Comment: データベースをインポートしたなら、mysqlエクスポートデータ中のURL情報をローカル環境のURLに置換しないと管理画面にアクセスできません。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。
Search-Replace-DBを用いて、データベースの情報を置換したら接続できました。
初歩的な事にも関わらず、教えて頂きありがとうございます！